# Mount encfs volume created by encfs4win on OS X or Linux

Tags: linux, macos, mount, encfs

I created a few encfs volumes on *Windows 7* using encfs4win. One is on Dropbox others are elswhere.

I am not able to mount these volumes on Linux or OS X. On Linux Mint I use the frontend *Cryptkeeper* and on OSX I tried it with *Macfusion*.

On both systems I get an error that says `folder is not empty`

**Any idea where my problem is?**

Answer (score 0):

Run encfsw.exe with Administrator rights. (%Program Files℅\encfs4win\encfsw.exe)